# RESTful api login security persistant

Tags: rest, restkit

I'm working on a RESTFul api for an IOS app and I've trouble with security.
I've many question so i post it here to have answer from pros.

So, first question is about login, I'm gonna use RESTKit to authenticate my users, but when user is logged-in how can I check if the user is authorized to get resource from REST?

I must use Token or something?
Create session when user is login?
Check at every request if user is login and have authorization to read/edit ressources?

I don't know if my question is stupid or if I miss something in RESTFul api use but if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about authorization can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853073/how-do-i-set-basic-authentication-with-restkit-0-20-0). When RestKit connects with the server the tokens received in the header of the response by the server are saved in a cache.

So if you reconnection or use GET/POST with the same object manager (and the session is still valide), there is no need to reauthorize - but it it's needed, RestKit will do it for you.

You can handle the cache by setting the `requestCache` of the object manager.