# Unable to create a Basic Authentication using RestKit with base 64 encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, restkit

I am trying to make Basic authentication and once I get the token, I will need to use base 64 encoding(For the encoding,I checked the new Data method for IOS7, but I won't be able to use it since it is IOS 7 only). So far, I was able to create a unsuccessful request based on this question base on a question [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853073/how-do-i-set-basic-authentication-with-restkit-0-20-0). Thus, I was unable to get the token.

**Question**

What is the practical way to do basic authentication and then use base 64 enconding with RestKit?

**App overview**

In my Login screen I ask only for the username and once the user logs in, I send a POST request to server to create account. In the same method, I create another Get request with different URL for Basic Authentication.

This is what the authentication data looks like:

```
{
  "Id": "255ab054",
  "TokenValidity": "00:00:00.1234567",
  "ValidTo": "2013-10-24T21:30:28.3295551+00:00",
  "Parameters": {},
  "Token": "sample string 3"
}
```

AccountClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface AccountsClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong,retain)NSString *DeviceType;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSNumber *AccountId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *NickName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *HardwareId;
@end
```

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSUUID *identifierForVendor;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreIdentifierForVendor;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreTheModel;
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *nickname;
@end
```

and then in LoginViewController.m, this is how I try to get the token:

```
[manager postObject:AccountInfo path:@"/Acounts/Tokn" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
    [manager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"NickName" password:@"HardwareId"];
```

to get the token(Which I believe, I am doing totally wrong.)

and finally this is the method that I am using in

LoginViewController.m

```
-(void)loadPostRequest
{
    _StoreIdentifierForVendor = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    _StoreTheModel = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    _nickname = usernameTextField.text;
     AccountsClass *AccountInfo = [[AccountsClass alloc] init];
    AccountInfo.NickName = _nickname;
    AccountInfo.HardwareId =[[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    AccountInfo.DeviceType =[UIDevice currentDevice].model;

      RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[AccountsClass class]];
      [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"NickName", @"HardwareId", @"DeviceType",@"AccountId"]];

    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
    RKResponseDescriptor *AccountDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"NickName", @"HardwareId", @"DeviceType",@"AccountId"]];
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[AccountInfo class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

      // First request is for to create the account using @"/Accounts" extension.
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net"]];
                                [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
                                [manager addResponseDescriptor:AccountDescriptor];
                                // POST to create
                                [manager postObject:AccountInfo path:@"/Acounts" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
    //And this is how I try to get the token
  [manager getObjectsAtPath:@"http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
[manager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"NickName" password:@"HardwareId"];
}
```

**This is what I get in the console:**

```
2013-10-24 23:17:40.259 GuessTheImage[6603:70b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2013-10-24 23:17:51.837 GuessTheImage[6603:70b] LoginViewController - Submit Action 
2013-10-24 23:17:51.913 GuessTheImage[6603:70b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 POST 'http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts'
2013-10-24 23:17:51.914 GuessTheImage[6603:70b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET 'http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn'
2013-10-24 23:17:52.187 GuessTheImage[6603:3d0b] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:547 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x8bc9160 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x8ba1b30> { URL: http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8bc7fe0> { URL: http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Fri, 25 Oct 2013 06:17:52 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=9505e3b43afb653bbcf6f6ed272f61c2ad5ee56489dc485c1ec82f9dee0c39b7;Path=/;Domain=quizstage.azurewebsites.net, WAWebSiteSID=ac6f8d6c21cc4e4782c818ce8b7705a7; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic Scheme='Quiz' location=http://{0}/Acount/Tokn";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET, ARR/2.5, ASP.NET";
} }}
2013-10-24 23:17:52.197 GuessTheImage[6603:3d0b] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:213 GET 'http://picquizstage.azurewebsites.net/Accounts/Token' (401 Unauthorized / 0 objects) [request=0.2724s mapping=0.0000s total=0.3571s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x8bc9160 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x8ba1b30> { URL: http://picquizstage.azurewebsites.net/Accounts/Token }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8bc7fe0> { URL: http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts/Tokn } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Fri, 25 Oct 2013 06:17:52 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=9505e3b43afb653bbcf6f6ed272f61c2ad5ee56489dc485c1ec82f9dee0c39b7;Path=/;Domain=quizstage.azurewebsites.net, WAWebSiteSID=ac6f8d6c21cc4e4782c818ce8b7705a7; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic Scheme='Quiz' location=http://{0}/Acount/Tokn";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET, ARR/2.5, ASP.NET";
} }}
2013-10-24 23:17:52.236 GuessTheImage[6603:3e07] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 POST 'http://quizstage.azurewebsites.net/Acounts' (201 Created / 1 objects) [request=0.3213s mapping=0.0014s total=0.4041s]
```

I read can map data using RestKit(without authentication), but I am pretty making API calls with authentication. I appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're going to make a POST request which returns 404? It should be defined by your server whether GET or POST should be used.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the the POST request. /Accounts needs to be POST but /Accounts/Token needs to GET. I updated that but I am still unable to authenticate. Any idea?

Comment: how about putting the last line of code `[manager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"NickName" password:@"HardwareId"];` just below `RKObjectManager` init method.

Comment: `setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername` should be called before `getObjectsAtPath`...

Comment: @Wain, hello Wain, I didn't saw your comment earlier. I wrote a new question with cleaner code also, I was not doing the base 64 correctly before. If you can take a look, that would be great! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647631/basic-authentication-using-restkit)