# Unknown type name 'RKObjectManager'

Tags: objective-c, restkit, cocoapods

Im doing a Restkit project for test some of the function of this package. I instaled Restkit 0.20 via cocoapods and for now, im trying to connect to a remote server using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853073/how-do-i-set-basic-authentication-with-restkit-0-20-0).

I followed all the tutorial step by step and all is installed and tried to declare the property RKObjectManager but im still having the same issue. What im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you imported RKObjectManager into your header/implementation file ?

Comment: I didnt know the issue was so simple, so i just add

    #import <RKObjectManager.h>

on the .pch file. I supose i will do the same in the future with other kind of objects that i will be using. 

Thanks for your help sbarow, i was having a lot of issues yesterday with other things and with this i didnt see something so simple.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest adding it to your .pch file unless you want it available throughout the project. It is better to add it to the header/implementation file for the class you created.

Comment: I see, i will do that right now and for future implementations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just import in your header file like that below.

If it is your custom class then import like that:-

```
#import "RKObjectManager.h"
```

If it is your framework class then import like that:-

```
#import <RestKit/RKObjectManager.h>
```